# how to pass javascript variable to php in template

Tags: magento2, php, template, uicomponent, jquery

I am creating admin form using template I have multiple select dropdown. I want to filter dropdown based on the value of other but problem is how i can assign the javascript value to php variable so that i can send the id to the function in block and it send me the filtered collection for another select dropdown

[image]

All the dropdown collections is coming from Block (methods). I want to filter **Level From** and **Level To** dropdown based on the selected value of **Color Code** Dropdown ,Now I can easily get the value of selected dropdown using jquery how i can pass that value to php so that i can filter the respective dropdown accordingly.

Please help Thanks in Advanced !!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on reverse, passing php data as options to a custom js AMD module so that it's all handled via js. 
Add listeners to each dropdown and based on the value selected render the options of the next dropdown.. 
I don't know if there's a better way, but it's an idea.